# Runtime consume record from the offset in kafka spring boot

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I want to read the record from the Kafka runtime passing parameter(offset).
I am using a `@KafkaListener` but in that, I am unable to set the offset runtime of the user request. And if no offset is passed it will consume the latest records. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The latest 2.8 release has a new feature where you can use the `KafkaTemplate` to receive a specific record at a specific offset.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#kafka-template-receive

If you want to receive all records from that offset, use the seek mechanisms provided by the container.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#seek

Comment: Hey, @Gary thanks for the answer. do you have a sample code of this or any reference?

Comment: There are tests here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/c061fce5988ef5f7eaf20a1f5fc6bfe41cbb9b4d/spring-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaTemplateTests.java#L196-L204